# Rails 6 form_with submits edit form as POST request, despite record being persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form in my app

```
= form_with model: @line_item, url: [:admin, @order, @line_item], local: true do |line_item|
```

Despite `@line_item.persisted?` returning true, I still get the following error:

`No route matches [POST] "/admin/orders/c01438684d/line_items/19"`

here's the applicable route

```
namespace :admin do    
  resources :orders do
    resources :line_items do
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried everything I can think of and at this point I'm stumped. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

With selected description from the error, it's hard to point out what exactly caused the errors. However, based on the available information - there are two areas you may to look into. The first is the namespacing in your routes.If you have admin namespace, make sure your route look something like -----------

```
namespace :admin do 
   resources :orders do
       resources :line_items do
    end
   end
 end
```

and the second at your form url - `form_with model: [:admin,@line_item], local: true do |line_item|` which will create a form that submits to `LineItems#Controller` inside a namespace eventually submitting to `admin_line_items_path(@line_items)` as described in [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-namespaces) and [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: thank you for your comment, after looking at your comment I realized that I had forgot to show the correct route to submit the form to, as well as the namespace declaration, which is present in my routes file.